# Como juntar grid con bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, video, bootstrap-carousel, grid

Estoy utilizando bootstrap para una página web, utilicé una grid con dos columnas para colocar un slider y un video de forma horizontal el cual quiero juntar, pero tengo un detalle entre slider y el video es tengo un espacio y quiero juntarlas

Este es mi codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px">
            <!--carousel-->
            <div class="header-content-right">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="prueba 1">
                            <!-- height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 1</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class=" img-responsive" alt="Second slide">
                            <!--height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 2</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Third slide">
                            <!-- height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 3</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-sm-6 ">
            <!--VIDEO -->
            <div id="video" class="header-content-right" style="margin:0px">
                <div class="delimitador">
                    <div class="contenedor">
                        <iframe src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls="controls"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por css youpuedes usar : style="margin-left:15px;".....margin-right..margin-top...etc...

Comment: este estilo agregalo en :<div class=" col-sm-6 " style=".....">

Comment: no he modifica de esa forma y todavía no me funciona ! :s

Comment: style="margin: 0px" estas poniendolo mal... fijate no especificas el tipo de margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre las columnas hay un espacio, quita el padding y el margin y listo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <!--carousel-->
            <div class="header-content-right">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="prueba 1">
                            <!-- height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 1</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class=" img-responsive" alt="Second slide">
                            <!--height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 2</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class=" d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Third slide">
                            <!-- height="80%" width="80%"-->
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>prueba 3</h5>
                                <p>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-sm-6 " style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <!--VIDEO -->
            <div id="video" class="header-content-right" style="margin:0px">
                <div class="delimitador">
                    <div class="contenedor">
                        <iframe style="height:100%;" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls="controls"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('.contenedor').height($('.carousel-inner').height());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```